# I'm trying to get a toString to print out in a group together after a loop is cancelled

Tags: java

This is what I have so far and I tried to use the while (yorn=="yes") to cancel but it keeps going regardless and I am also trying to find a way to make it so the outputs go in one group together rather than being seperated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String no = "no";
    String yes = "yes";
    String yorn="yes";

    CollegeStudent Student1 = new CollegeStudent();

    while (yorn=="yes") {
      System.out.println("continue? yes/no:");
      yorn=scan.next();
      Student1.setname();
      Student1.setcourseTitle();
      Student1.setcredits();
      Student1.setcourseCode();
      System.out.println(Student1.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `equals` method for string comparing in the `java`:

```
while (yorn.equals("yes"))
{
    System.out.println("continue? yes/no:");
    yorn=scan.next();
    Student1.setname();
    Student1.setcourseTitle();
    Student1.setcredits();
    Student1.setcourseCode();
    System.out.println(Student1.toString());
}
```

Since after you answer exists the logic in the cicle, after `yes` typing code has been executing anyway (one time). Simply solution for you will be:

```
System.out.println("Do you need to add a student? yes/no:");
yorn=scan.next();
while (yorn.equals("yes"))
{
    Student1.setname();
    Student1.setcourseTitle();
    Student1.setcredits();
    Student1.setcourseCode();
    System.out.println(Student1.toString());
    System.out.println("continue? yes/no:");
    yorn=scan.next();
}
```

Comment: it still runs the command and doesn't exit it :(

Comment: @EshaRice I updated answer

Comment: oh okay, that makes much more sense now, I appreciate it!